JMeter 5.6.3: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.charting.DateTimeRenderer
I have inherited a legacy load testing project.
When I try to open the .jmx file, then I get a pop-up window with the error inscribed and the text inside is kg/apc/charting/DateTimeRenderer
I'm using Apache JMeter Version 5.6.3.
Error logs:
> 2024-10-15 10:48:00,466 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/bin'
2024-10-15 10:48:00,469 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: /Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads/Stepping_load_7.jmx
2024-10-15 10:48:00,469 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads'
2024-10-15 10:48:00,469 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads/Stepping_load_7.jmx
2024-10-15 10:48:00,524 WARN o.j.r.PluginManager: Found JAR conflict: /Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/lib/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10 — копия.jar and /Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/lib/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10.jar
2024-10-15 10:48:00,524 WARN o.j.r.PluginManager: Found JAR conflict: /Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10 — копия.jar and /Users/lyatipovrinat/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/lib/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.10 — копия.jar
2024-10-15 10:48:00,524 WARN o.j.r.p.PluginSuggester: Plugins Manager were unable to find plugins to satisfy Test Plan requirements. To help improve, please report following list to https://jmeter-plugins.org/support/: [kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroupGui]
2024-10-15 10:48:00,537 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2024-10-15 10:48:00,538 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to UTF-8
2024-10-15 10:48:00,538 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2024-10-15 10:48:00,538 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2024-10-15 10:48:00,576 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Missing jar file. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/charting/DateTimeRenderer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/charting/DateTimeRenderer
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:462) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:236) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:555) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:201) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:132) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:103) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:90) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:83) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773) ~[?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720) ~[?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400) [?:?]
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) [?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) [?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.charting.DateTimeRenderer
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:595) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:528) ~[?:?]
    ... 28 more
2024-10-15 10:48:00,576 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: kg/apc/charting/DateTimeRenderer

Has anyone encountered this?
I have tried to install other versions of JMeter but it didn't help.

Please add jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter jar in the /lib/ext or /lib directory
I took the latest version that is 0.7 at the time of writing the answer. It has the kg.apc.charting.DateTimeRenderer class in it.

We cannot provide comprehensive help without seeing the full error and jmeter.log file
I can only assume that your .jmx script relies on a certain JMeter Plugin which is not installed.
Try adding JMeter Plugins Manager to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation and restarting JMeter, if my assumption is correct the Plugins Manager will detect missing plugins and suggest to install them.
